# How do I reverse data in r studio from a dataset?

Tags: r, factors

I have a dataset from ESS for R cloud. I want to reorder the levels of one question in the dataset in order to make it easier to compare it to another one.

The factor levels are ("Worse place to live", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Better place to live") and they each have values of the number of participants who choose that answer. Now I need it to be ("Better place to live", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Worse place to live"). I tried to do it with mapvalues, but it just changed the label and not the values that it was holding. 
So maybe you guy can help me!. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order and then do a `sort`

```
sort(factor(v1, levels = c("Better place to live", 9:1, "Worse place to live")))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Worse place to live", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Better place to live")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life and a lot of my time !!!

Comment: might need your help again. So when i called the variable v1 it all worked out fine. Now i set everything up in a new R project (The other one was pretty messy).
Now I have this code chunk.
```{r}
ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive <- sort(factor(ESS$imwbcnt, levels = c("Better place to live", 9:1, "Worse place to live")))
table(ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive)
class(ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive)
```
And I get this message, just because it has another name: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, worseorbetterplacetolive, value = c(1L, : replacement has 42825 rows, data has 44387"

Comment: @charliewillkillya   can you check the unique elements of `unique(ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive)`. and if it is the same or have diffferent values than the one provided in `levels`

Comment: I think I got the issue,  you may have `NA` elements in your data.  check `sort(c(1, 2, NA))#
[1] 1 2
> ?sort
> sort(c(1, 2, NA), na.last = TRUE)#
[1]  1  2 NA`. So, in this case, you may need `sort(factor(ESS$imwbcnt, levels = c("Better place to live", 9:1, "Worse place to live")), na.last = TRUE)`

Comment: So I just took out the $ sign in the variable names and suddenly the problem disappeared. Guess everything is alright now.

Comment: @charliewillkillya do you have a matrix or data.frame. With `matrix`, the `$` won't work.  you need `[`

Comment: And yeah there are NA's in my data, but we have to do the whole stuff a certain way and taking out the NA's is the last step for whatever reason.

Comment: I would add `na.last = TRUE` and then rremove the NA rows with `na.omit` after the assignment because when you. do the assignment to the old dataset, its NA elementss are not removed and this causes the difference in length error or consider removing the `NA` rows before the `sort`